# Bitwise operators giving me hell

Tags: c#, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the xbox 360's STFS file structure, and the page I'm reading gave this code example for finding the offset of a code block:

```
internal int BlockToOffset(int xBlock)
{
    int xReturn = 0;
    if (xBlock > 0xFFFFFF)
        xReturn = -1;
    else
        xReturn = (((MetaData.HeaderSize + 0xFFF) & 0xF000) + (xBlock << 12));
    return xReturn;
}
```

`xBlock` would be the block number you're trying to find the offset for. 
I'm not sure what the significance of the header size is, but I think it determines how much of the rest of the code is offset by. Anyway, I can't make sense of what the bitwise operators are doing. The headersize is 38682, and block 0 IS at 0xA000, but again, I have no clue how that works.

Can someone please help me here?

edit: Any information on the use of bitwise operators would be great. I understand how they work, but I just don't understand how they are used, especially in this case, which seems to be pushing their efficiency.

Comment: Its a bit of an open question, anyways, http://www.arkem.org/xbox360-file-reference.pdf should explain nicely how the file structure works.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look. edit: oh boy, it looks like thats where the information I've been reading was copied from. http://www.free60.org/STFS#Hash_Tables_.2F_Block_Offsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets break it apart starting from the end:

```
xBlock << 12
```

This left shift operator tells us that the block size is 4096 since:

```
1 << 12 = 1000000000000 (binary) = 4096 (decimal)
```

Now, the first part is adding a constant to the header size:

```
MetaData.HeaderSize + 0xFFF
```

0xFFF is 4095. Notice that it's just 1 less than 4096.

```
1000000000000 (4096 in binary)
0111111111111 (4095 in binary)
```

The next part is now clearing the lower 12 bits, since 0xF000 in binary is:

```
1111000000000000 (1111 followed by 12 0s)
```

So, as far as I can tell, what's happening is:

**1)** Take the header size and add a block size - 1

**2)** Clear out the lower 12 bits which is rounding to the next largest closest multiple of a block size. <strike>I'm not 100% sure of this part but I tried some examples of (001 + 111) & 1000 vs (111 + 111) & 1000 and it seems like that's what it's doing.</strike>

**3)** The current value is where the offset for block 0 starts, so add on the appropriate multiple of 4096 to get the block's offset

Comment: You're right about the rounding. What the code in effect does is reserve a number of pages for the metadata and store each 4096 byte block in its own page after that.

Comment: @SebastiaanMegens, Woah, you know about the STFS file structure? Can you help me out a bit?

Comment: Alright, so it's seeing how many blocks the header takes up, and then adds the block number multiplied by their size?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down:

```
(MetaData.HeaderSize + 0xFFF) & 0xF000
```

This part is essentially "find the next highest multiple of 0x1000", similar to a "ceiling" function.
For example, if the `HeaderSize` is from 0x0001 to 0x1000, it will round to 0x1000.  But if it is from 0x1001 to 0x2000, it will round to 0x2000, etc.

```
(xBlock << 12)
```

This is the same as `xBlock * 0x1000`, because 2^12 = 0x1000 = 4096.

So, to find your offset, you take the header, find the next highest multiple of 0x1000, and add 0x1000 for each block.